# How can I make a method wait for an Input from another class?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have a class that opens a window with a list, of which the user can select one item. All of that works, if a list item is selected, the value gets stored and there is a button in the window that saves the value and closes the window.

This is what the window looks like.

[image]

Now to my problem: I need a method that returns the value that is selected when the user clicks "OK". My attempt looks like this:

```
public Field returnSelectedField() {
    FieldSelector fs = new FieldSelector(); //FieldSelector is the class I mentioned before
    return fs.saved;
}
```

The problem is, that this method continues running instantly, so it does not wait for the user to click the button and save his selection. Now, I have read about multi-threading and making the class this method is in wait for the other class to finish running, but I have not found a tutorial where I understood how that could work.

I would greatly appreciate, if one of you more experienced coders had a link to a simple tutorial or an idea for a solution for this problem. I guess there is a simple one, which I am just not capable of finding.

Comment: How do you handle what happens when the button is clicked? Is the "OK" button the same button that saves the value and closes the window that you mentioned? As that's the only button i see on the image.

Comment: Yes, it is. Pressing the button saves the value in the "saved" variable in the class and closes the window.

Comment: So, how do you handle that button event? - If its possible to show your method(s). Also, just to clarify, you're using Swing yes?

Comment: I think you are facing the problem you have in the wrong way. Getting input using a list widget and passing that input to the business logic should't involve multithreading (at least at the high level you are programing). It should be resolved with callbacks most propably.

Comment: @KleoG Ah wait, I was wrong. I have a ListSelectionListener that saves the selected value in the saved variable, the only thing the button does is closing the window. So the ListSelectionListener runs the following method with the selected value as parameter:
`public void verarbeitung(Object o) {
  String name = o.toString();
  for (int i = 0; i < globalList.size(); i++) {
   if (name.equals(globalList.get(i).getName())) {
    saved = globalList.get(i);
   }
  }
 } `

Comment: @Juan Thanks for your suggestion. Do you know a place where I can learn about callbacks from ground up? I have read a little bit, but didn't grasp the concept instantly, so if you know a place, I would be grateful. Otherwise I will continue googling myself :)

Comment: I suggest you go with a tutorial of javafx or the framework you have chosen  for the user interface. If you want the theory of how it works look into the observer pattern.  At a high level the idea is that the business logic gets hooked up on to the ui elements of interest and the ui, when it receives an input, notifies what it has received to all it's hooked objects from the business logic so they can take action on the input.

Comment: @Juan Thanks for your help, I will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this material will be useful 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

It has good example with buttons)

It`s official documentation on Listeners, if it will be too hard for you to understand, try to find smth on that theme

Briefly -  ActionListener  is a class that "listen" or wait for some event, in your case - button pressing, and when it happens starts to performing some actions that you want)

```
public Field selected;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     selected =  fs.saved;

}

public Field returnSelectedField() {  

   return selected;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but handling the button's action isn't my problem, I think. It's more about getting a return value out of the method I mentioned, and having the method basically wait for a value from the list I opened.

Comment: @Ceratius Maybe i dont fully inderstand you, but as far as i understand, you dont need your method, you can add ActionListener to your button, so when user performs a action(pressing button)  - `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method is invoked, so in this method you can get a value what you need

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that I need a method that returns that value. Since actionPerformed has to be a void method, that is not possible, or is there a way?

Comment: @Ceratius No, you cant return value directly from `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`
But i corrected my first answer, to show what is a possibility to do this =) Have a look